Portable launcher for pdoc
I have a Python package hosted in a private GitHub space. I want to distribute it with a batch file that launches pdoc (we can assume all users are on Windows). I wrote such a batch file for myself, and it's only one line:
"C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\Scripts\pdoc.exe" my_package

The problem is that the Python path is installation-dependent. How do I make the batch file portable?
I considered making a Python script to launch pdoc, using this example, but the example seems to generate a single HTML file, which is a small part of the functionality of pdoc.exe.
I then tried to write a short Python script, embedded within a python -c "do stuff" construct, to build the needed command string (using sys.executable). I got a syntax error.
I came up with a solution that works (see below) but decided to post the question anyway in case someone has a better one.

The best I could come up with was a Python script that generates a batch file. The user needs to run this script in a Python interpreter to "install" the batch file.
import sys

pdoc_path = sys.executable.replace(
    'python.exe', 'scripts/pdoc.exe')

with open('pdocgen.bat', 'w') as fid:
    fid.write(f'"{pdoc_path}" my_package\n')

